# \cite coming up as (?) in texstudio with the error message

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

I am using a thesis template from the following link
The original version of the thesis and the CHARM website can be found at: http://charm-mist.appspot.com.
The same had been used by my senior also.

The references is not appearing when compiling the document. Also the \cite are appearing as (?)
I have manually put in the citations but would prefer latex to pick it up and fill up the reference section.

```
Process started: bibtex "BRMphd".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: BRMphd.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 11_backmatter/BRMdeclaration.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 11_backmatter/BRMcertificate.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/BRMabstract.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/BRMdedication.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 0_frontmatter/BRMacknowledgement.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 11_backmatter/BRMpub.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 1/BRMintro.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 2/BRMinstrumentation.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 9/Codes.aux
The style file: Latex/Classes/jmb.bst
I couldn't open database file 9_backmatter/BRMref.bib
---line 53 of file BRMphd.aux
 : \bibdata{9_backmatter/BRMref
 :                             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file BRMphd.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Taylor:2013"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Taylor:2015"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Nichols:1997AAS"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Garhart:1997IUENNV2"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Nichols:1996"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Nichols-Bohlin:1990ESASP"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "HI4PI:2016A&A"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "FerlandOsterbrock:1987ApJ318145F"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Davisdon:1977ApJ21820D"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "DavisdonNet:1979RvMP51715D"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Ferland1Mushotzky:982ApJ262564F"
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

The text is as follows

```
Tool for OPerations on Catalogues And Tables or (TOPCAT)\footnote{http://www.starlink.ac.uk/topcat/} as it is generally called (Taylor, 2013) \citep{Taylor:2013StaUNT} is a desktop GUI (Graphical User Interface) for analysis of tabular data, particularly source catalogue (Taylor, 2015) \citep{Taylor:2015ASPCT}.
```

[image: reference section is empty]
[image: citations coming as question mark beside manually typed citations]

Comment: Did you run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: Off-topic: Please immediately replace all instances of  `{\it ` with `\textit{`, followed by deletingthe whitespace between `{` and `\textit{`.

Comment: I have done the compiling in texstudio. Everything is fine except the \cite part.

Comment: When I run bibliography in texstudio, it give the following output                                                     "I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file BRMphd.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Taylor:2013"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Taylor:2015""

Comment: `I couldn't open database file 9_backmatter/BRMref.bib` suggests that BibTeX does not find your `.bib` file where you say it is. Check that the file name is correct and remember that file references are resolved relative to the working directory, which is usually the same directory where your main `.tex` file lives.